# --immediate-submit {dependencies} string contains script paths, not job IDs?

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to use the --immediate-submit on a PBSPro cluster. I tried using an in-place modification of the dependencies string to adapt it to PBSPro, similar to what is done [here](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/662/).

```
snakemake --cluster "qsub -l wd -l mem={cluster.mem}GB -l ncpus={threads} -e {cluster.stderr} -q {cluster.queue} -l walltime={cluster.walltime} -o {cluster.stdout} -S /bin/bash -W $(echo '{dependencies}' | sed 's/^/depend=afterok:/g' | sed 's/ /:/g')"
```

This last part gets converted into, for example:

```
-W depend=afterok: /g/data1a/va1/dk0741/analysis/2018-03-25_marmo_test/.snakemake/tmp.cyrhf51c/snakejob.trimmomatic_pe.7.sh
```

There are two problems here:

1. How can I get the dependencies string to output job ID instead of the script path? The qsub command normally outputs the job ID to stdout, so I'm not sure why it's not doing so here.
2. How do I get rid of the space after `afterok:`? I've tried everything!

As an aside, it would be helpful if there were some option to debug the submission or not to delete the `tmp.cyrhf51c` directory in .snakemake -- is there some way to do this?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a profile for this, instead of trying to find an ad-hoc solution. This will also help with debugging. E.g., there is already a pbs-torque profile available (https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/pbs-torque), probably there is not much to change towards pbspro?

Comment: Thanks Johannes, I'll try looking into profiles. But I am still very surprised that the dependencies string spits out the script path instead of the job ID.

Comment: Yes, me as well. Snakemake simply takes stdout of the called submission command.